# Inverse of continuous bijection between compact metric spaces is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ be compact metric spaces and $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous bijection. Prove that $f^{-1}:Y\to X$ is also continuous.

Since $(Y, d_Y)$ is compact, it is totally bounded. Thus, for every $\delta>0, \exists y_1, \dots, y_n\in X$ such that $X\subset \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n \underbrace{\overline{B_\delta(y_k)}}_\text{closed ball about $x_k$}$. So let $\delta > 0$.

Since $(X, d_X)$ is totally bounded, $\forall\epsilon>0, \exists x_1, \dots, x_m\in X$ such that $X\subset \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^m {\overline{B_\epsilon(x_k)}}$. So let $\epsilon > 0$.

Let $y_0\in Y$, then $y_0$ is in some $\delta$-ball $B_\delta(y_i)$ for $1\le i \le n$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}$ pulls back closed sets to closed sets, so that $f^{-1}\left(\overline{B_\delta(y_i)}\cap Y\right)\subset \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^m \overline{B_{\epsilon}(x_i)}\cap X$. Hence $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Would appreciate if someone could look at my proof and let me know whether or not it is correct.

Comment: $f$ continuous means $f$ pulls back open sets to open sets. So you start with a $y_0 \in Y$, and given is some $\varepsilon>0$ and you want some $\delta > 0$ such that $f^{-1}[B(y, \delta)]\ \subseteq B(f^{-1}(y_0), \varepsilon)$. You only know the left hand side is open, but produce no recipe to make $\delta$ such that the inclusion holds.

Comment: Way easier is to use $f$ is a closed map (as it sends closed=compact subsets of $X$ to compact=closed subsets of $Y$).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Can you please take a look now? I've edited it.

Comment: You don't show at all it *does* hold. How do you make $\delta$ from $\varepsilon$? Whether you use closures of balls or open balls makes no difference.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Can we choose $\delta$ based on how many $\epsilon$-balls there are for $X$? Say, if we need $m$ $\epsilon$-balls to cover $X$, then we require $m$ $\delta$-balls to cover $Y$. But then we are still not guaranteed to have the needed inclusion, I think.

Comment: No, it doesn't follow from total boundedness alone. You would need completeness too. If you don't use the closed map argument you might go with sequences (or better nets, if you know about those).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use that $f$ is a closed map: if $C \subseteq X$ is closed, then $C$ is compact as a closed subset of the compact $X$. $f$ continuous then implies that $f[C]$ is compact as well, and in a metric space we have that compact subsets are closed, so $f[C]$ is closed. Finally note that $f[C] = (f^{-1})^{-1}[C]$ so $f^{-1}$ pulls back closed sets to closed sets, so is continuous.

Comment: Can you please clarify how does it follow from $f[C] = (f^{-1})^{-1}[C]$ that $f^{-1}$ pulls back closed sets to closed sets?

Comment: @sequence. For clarification call the inverse function of $f$ just $g: Y \to X$. We want to prove $g$ continuous so for any closed $C \subseteq X$ we want $g^{-1}[C]$ closed. But $g^{-1}[C]  =f[C]$ by simple set theory.